# a question about integral? I have no idea about that!

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If f(x) and g(x) are integrable in [a,b], can we say that f(x)g(x) is still integrable in [a,b]?

I am referring to Riemann integration!

Comment: Nope. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Try thinking of functions with vertical asymptotes at $a$ that are still integrable (I assume you mean either Lebesgue integrable or improper Riemann integrable; if you're referring to Riemann integration, then the answer is yes).

Comment: I am referring to Riemann integration instead of improper or Lebesgue integration. But why it is right for Riemann integration?

Comment: A bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities has measure $0$; the set of discontinuities of $fg$ is contained in the union of the sets for $f$ and $g$ individually - this union still has measure $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the product of bounded functions is bounded, so since $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable, $fg$ is bounded too. Furthermore, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$, so is $fg$; hence we have the inclusion

$$\{x : fg \text{ is not continuous at } x\} \subseteq \{x : f \text{ not continuous}\} \cup \{x : g \text{ not continuous}\}$$

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, the set of its discontinuities has Lebesgue measure $0$ (that is, it can be contained within a collection of open intervals whose lengths sum to an arbitrarily small number). The same is true for $g$, and so the union still has measure $0$.

Thus $fg$ is bounded and its set of discontinuities is sufficiently small, so $fg$ is Riemann integrable.